# i am submitting my form with php but it is going to spam

Tags: php, html, smtp, gmail, smtpclient

**> the mail posted with the below given is going to spam. I am not using

> captcha in the form as i don want to. So can anybody help me to the
>   mail in Inbox**

```
 <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $name = $_POST['Name'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $phone = $_POST['phone'];
            $date = $_POST['checkinDate'];
            $package = $_POST['package'];
            $person = $_POST['adults'];
            $kids = $_POST['kids'];
            $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //trace the ip address of the user submited

            $subject ="Query From  :Kerala-Honeymoon-Packages - Promotion\n"; //subject of the email
            $to="paul@roverholidays.com";
            $cc="online@roverholidays.com";
            $ccc="deepti@roverholidays.com";

            $from=$_POST['email'];
            $adc="Name :$name\n";
            $adc.="Email :$email\n";
            $adc.="Phone :$phone\n";
            $adc.="Date of Travel :$date\n";
            $adc.="Package :$package\n";
            $adc.="Adults :$person\n";
            $adc.="Kids :$kids\n";
            $message ="$name copy of the query you submited in Kerala-Honeymoon-Packages";//message header to user submited
            $headers="From: <".$from. ">" ; 

            mail($cc,$subject,$adc,$headers);
            mail($ccc,$subject,$adc,$headers);
            mail($email,$message,$adc);
            header("Location: thanks.htm");
            }
                else
            {
                return false;
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: That has something to do with the mail spam filter. Might be triggered by some keywords like package, promotion, .... There are many rules for spam filter, I'm just guessing

Comment: If you are sending to your own mailbox, you can add the sender address as trusted.

Answer (score 0):

coding-wise I don't think there is anything you can do because it is the email server that classifies your email as a spam not the way you coded your script. All you can do is to control it from the receiver email setting i.e you setup your gmail filters to detect that email based on keyword like "Kerala-Honeymoon-Packages" and move it out of spam.

I don't know for sure what the email servers algorithms are for marking email as spam. However, I think sending email from different domain rather than your domain name is likely to be detected as phishing email. what I mean is when someone put his/her yahoo email in the form  and click on send, your server will send the email to emails addresses in the script but it will send it as if it came from yahoo, which will be suspicious for the receiver email server as it knows that it did not come from yahoo.

Answer (score 0):

Many email services block mail sent directly from random servers because they have little to no reputation as a legitimate source of non-spam emails.  Instead of using the straight php `mail()` function, try using a SMTP service like Mandrill or Gmail's SMTP service.  Both are free.

Here is the configuration page for Mandrill: 
http://help.mandrill.com/entries/23737696-How-do-I-send-with-PHPMailer-

```
<?php
require 'class.phpmailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->IsSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.mandrillapp.com';                 // Specify main and backup server
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // Set the SMTP port
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'MANDRILL_USERNAME';                // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'MANDRILL_APIKEY';                  // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

$mail->From = 'from@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Your From name';
$mail->AddAddress('josh@example.net', 'Josh Adams');  // Add a recipient
$mail->AddAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional

$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <strong>in bold!</strong>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->Send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo 'Message has been sent';
```